# WCF Service - Message / Object size related

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, wcf-binding, wcf-configuration

I have wcf service (S1) as client and another Wcf service(S2) as server. S1 consume S2 over net.tcp. S2 has one operation, which return a complex object with most of it's contents are string. The average size of this object is between 7-8 MB.

Recently I had to add more string contents to the actual object graph. This cause S2 to return following error

> The socket connection was aborted. This could be caused by an error
>   processing your message or a receive timeout being exceeded by the
>   remote host, or an underlying network resource issue. Local socket
>   timeout was '00:05:00'. System.Net.Sockets.SocketException
>   (0x80004005): An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote
>   host    at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32
>   offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.ReadCore(Byte[] buffer,
>   Int32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout, Boolean closing)

However, everything works as expected when I remove some of the string contents from the object graph.

After doing bit of a homework,I was managed to land on a conclusion that, it has something to do with the size of the returned object. This made me to revise my client and service configuration/quota's.

However, I have no luck even after modifying the client and service especially size related attributes.

Can someone guide me on this?  Please ask me for more information if needed.

Thanks in advance.

**Client (S1)**

```
<netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="NetTcp" closeTimeout="00:05:00"
          openTimeout="00:05:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:05:00"
          transactionFlow="false" transferMode="Buffered" transactionProtocol="OleTransactions"
          hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" listenBacklog="10" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
          maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxConnections="10" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
            maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
            enabled="false" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign" />
            <message clientCredentialType="Windows" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
    <client>
          <endpoint address="net.tcp://xxxxxxxx/xxxxxxService"
            binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="NetTcp" behaviorConfiguration="RBehavior"  
            contract="IService" name="NetTcp" />
        </client>
        <services/>

        <behaviors>
          <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="NSBehavior">
              <etwTracking profileName="EndToEndMonitoringProfile"/>
              <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false"/>
              <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
            </behavior> 

          </serviceBehaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>                                   
                <behavior name="RBehavior">
     **<dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />**
                </behavior>
            </endpointBehaviors>
        </behaviors>

        <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
      </system.serviceModel>

     <system.webServer>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
      </system.webServer>
```

**Server (S2)**

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="netTcp" closeTimeout="00:03:00"
          openTimeout="00:03:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:03:00"
          transactionFlow="false" transferMode="Buffered" transactionProtocol="OleTransactions"
          hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" listenBacklog="10" maxBufferPoolSize="20000000"
          maxBufferSize="20000000" maxConnections="10" maxReceivedMessageSize="20000000">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="20000000"
            maxArrayLength="20000000" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
            enabled="false" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign" />
            <message clientCredentialType="Windows" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>

    <services>
      <service name="Engine.Rules"
               behaviorConfiguration="REServiceBehavior">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://xxxxx:8005/Service"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <endpoint address=""
                  binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="netTcp"
                  contract="Ixxxx" />
        <endpoint address="mex"
                  binding="mexTcpBinding"
                  contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="REServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false"/>
      **<dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>**
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>  
          <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentSessions="1000"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

**Update**: As per @ErikFunkenbusch's sensible support, I am attaching service trace information.[image: Exception]

```
<ExceptionString>System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: The socket connection was aborted. This could be caused by an error processing your message or a receive timeout being exceeded by the remote host, or an underlying network resource issue. Local socket timeout was '00:05:00'. ---&gt; System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.ReadCore(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout, Boolean closing)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---</ExceptionString>
<InnerException>
<ExceptionType>System.Net.Sockets.SocketException, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType>
<Message>An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host</Message>
<StackTrace>
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.ReadCore(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout, Boolean closing)
</StackTrace>
<ExceptionString>System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.ReadCore(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout, Boolean closing)</ExceptionString>
<NativeErrorCode>2746</NativeErrorCode>
</InnerException>
</Exception>
```

Comment: Rather than just randomly setting stuff, why don't you just enable message tracing on the server and then look at the tracing log to see which value needs to be increased?

Comment: I have no luck in setting tracing for these individual service. Any advise on how to set this for net.tcp binding?

Comment: What do you mean by "no luck"?  Tracing is very simple and works the same for all WCF services regardless of transport.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch, Thanks for the link. I did enabled tracing. No trace is recorded. Further, the S2 is a wcf hosted using windows service and S1 is  wcf hosted in IIS.

Comment: Doesn't matter if it's hosted by a windows service.  You do need to make sure it writes the log to a location that the service has permission to write to.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch, Thanks. I could now get trace log. Earlier it was failing due to permission on the directory. Much appreciated. However, the error I couldn't translate errors and is going above my head. I will be updating my initial post with trace log/ Image. Please help.

Comment: Those are exceptions in the Receive method, that's strange because your server should be SENDING data...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried increasing the send and receive timeout values? You're sending a lot of data over the wire (7-8MB) and 5 seconds may not be enough time to complete that transaction. Try setting them to something like 30 seconds and then working from there.

E:

```
<binding name="netTcp" closeTimeout="00:30:00"
      openTimeout="00:30:00" receiveTimeout="00:30:00" sendTimeout="00:30:00">
```

That is what I'm referring to, specifically.

Comment: It is 5 and 3 minutes.